# Actualizar inventario

Tags: c#, sql-server

Tengo un procedimiento almacenado para actualizar la existencia de mi inventario. Este es el código en `SQL`:

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_ActualizaInventario]
 @cantidad INT
,@Producto INT
,@Tipo INT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Existencia INT 
SET @Existencia = (SELECT Existencia FROM maestraproductoinventario WHERE [Codigo De Articulo] = @Producto)
if(@Tipo = 1)
begin
UPDATE
 maestraproductoinventario 
 SET
    Existencia = @Existencia - @cantidad 
    WHERE [Codigo De Articulo] = @Producto
end
else
begin
UPDATE
 maestraproductoinventario 
 SET
    Existencia = @Existencia + @cantidad 
    WHERE [Codigo De Articulo] = @Producto
end
END
```

lo uso asi en c#:

```
SqlConnection conec = new SqlConnection();
SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand();
cm.Connection = con;
cm.CommandText = "SP_ActualizaInventario";
cm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@cantidad", SqlDbType.Int));
cm.Parameters["@cantidad"].Value = txtcantidad.Text.Trim();

cm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Producto", SqlDbType.Int));
cm.Parameters["@Producto"].Value = txtcodigo.Text.Trim();

cm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Tipo", SqlDbType.Int));
cm.Parameters["@Tipo"].Value = 2;

con.Open();
cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

y cuando lo utilizo en la compra me da un error de tipo de dato, me dice esto:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>   Additional information: Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32.

No entiendo por qué, ¿alguien tiene una idea?

Answer (score 0):

El problema lo veo en estas dos líneas:

```
cm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@cantidad", SqlDbType.Int));
cm.Parameters["@cantidad"].Value = txtcantidad.Text.Trim();
```

Ya que en la primera estás definiendo el tipo de columna en `Int`, y en la segunda estás asignando un valor `string`, lo que debes hacer es algo así en la segunda línea:

```
cm.Parameters["@cantidad"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtcantidad.Text.Trim());
```

Así estás convirtiendo el texto que hay en `txtcantidad` en un dato de tipo **número entero**.

Un mejor control sobre eso quizás sería hacerlo con [int.TryParse](https://www.dotnetperls.com/parse):

```
int _dato = 0;
int.TryParse(txtcantidad.Text.Trim(), out _dato);
cm.Parameters["@cantidad"].Value = _dato;
```

para asegurarte que siempre vas a tener un número.
Finalmente, te dejo [esta referencia sobre las conversiones de texto a número](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/32885/difference-between-int-parse-convert-toint-and) para que veas las opciones que hay.

Comment: buenas, primero gracias por tomarte el tiempo de comentar, utiliza el codigo que digiste en la segunda linea y me da este error>

Comment: input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: Debes asegurarte que el texto sea un número. En caso de que no lo sea, prueba con el código de `TryParse` que te dejé un poco más abajo.

Comment: Ok el código de mas abajo lo sustituyó por la parte de la cantidad osea la segunda línea que ya sustitui

Comment: Así es, en lugar de utilizar el `Convert.ToInt32(...)` utiliza el bloque de más abajo para que no te dé el error.

Comment: Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32.

Comment: cm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@cantidad", SqlDbType.Int));
            int _dato = 0;
            int.TryParse(txtcantidad.Text.Trim(), out _dato);
            cm.Parameters["@cantidad"].Value = _dato;

Comment: puse ese codigo y me dio el error de arriba

Comment: Debes hacer lo mismo para el parámetro `@Producto`, ya que igualmente es un tipo de dato *Integer* en la base de datos pero le estás mandando una cadena.

Comment: aun sigue diciendome input string was not in the correct format